# how could I use mockito-kotlin to check the ProducerFactory?

Tags: kotlin, mockito, spring-kafka

I have a small piece of code on Kotlin in which Producer is configured.

```
testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
testImplementation("org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:4.1.0")
```

- properties

```kotlin
@ConfigurationProperties("initial")
data class KafkaProperties (

    @field:NotEmpty
    var topic: String = "topic",

    @field:NestedConfigurationProperty
    val kafka: KafkaProperties = KafkaProperties()
)
```

- record

```kotlin
class Event (val id: Long) {
}
```

- producer

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(KafkaProperties::class)
class KafkaConfiguration (
    private val properties: KafkaProperties
) {

    @Bean
    fun initialProducerFactory(customizers: ObjectProvider<DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer>):
            ProducerFactory<String,Event> {

        val producerProperties = this.properties.kafka.buildProducerProperties()

        val factory =
            buildFactory(producerProperties)

        customizers.orderedStream()
            .forEach {
                    customizer -> customizer.customize(factory)
            }

        return factory
    }

    private fun buildFactory(producerProperties: Map<String, Any>):
            DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, Event> {

        val factory = DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, Event>(producerProperties)

        factory.keySerializer = StringSerializer()

        val objectMapper = JacksonUtils.enhancedObjectMapper().disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
        val jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer<Event>(objectMapper)

        factory.valueSerializer = jsonSerializer

        val transactionIdPrefix = this.properties.kafka.producer.transactionIdPrefix
        if (transactionIdPrefix != null) {
            factory.setTransactionIdPrefix(transactionIdPrefix)
        }
        return factory
    }
}
```

- service

```kotlin
@Service
class ServiceImpl(
    private val kafkaProperties: KafkaProperties,
    private val producerFactory: ProducerFactory<String, Event>
) : Service {
  private fun runPublishEventToKafka(Long id){

        val eventRequest = Event(id)
        val topic = kafkaProperties.topic

  val producer =  this.producerFactory.createProducer()
 
 producer.send(ProducerRecord(topic, eventRequest))
}
}
```

I made a small blank in the test class

```
class ServiceImplTest {
  
    private val kafkaProperties: KafkaProperties = mock()
    private val producerFactory: ProducerFactory<String, Event> = mock()

   
    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        

       // val producerFactory =
            mock<ProducerFactory<String, Event>>()

      //  val eventRequest = Event(1L)
      //  val topicTest = "topic.test"

      //  val producer = producerFactory.createProducer()
      //  val send = producer.send(ProducerRecord(topicTest, eventClosureRequest))

        whenever(producer.send(any())

        ).thenReturn(????) //fail
    }
    
    @Test
   fun test(){
     //....
   }
```

Who has any ideas on how to make a stub for calling a method -

**producer.send (...)**

?

**Update**

```kotlin
class ServiceImplTest {
    private val persistenceService: PersistenceService = mock()
    private val kafkaProperties: KafkaProperties  = mock()
    
     val user = TestUserFactory().user()
    ..........
    
    lateinit var sut: ServiceImpl

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        val mockProducerFactory = mock<ProducerFactory<String, Event>>()
        val mockProducer = mock<Producer<String, Event>>()

        sut = ServiceImpl(
            PersistenceService,
            kafkaProperties,
            mockProducerFactory)

        whenever(mockProducerFactory.createProducer()).thenReturn(mockProducer)
        whenever(persistenceService.loadUserById(any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(user))
    }
```

Here is another example of a class where mock had to be embedded to simulate calling the producer.send(.....) method

```java
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(
    initializers = [RedisInit::class, DBContainerInit::class],
    classes = [ServiceImpl::class, DataSourceConfiguration::class]
)
@Import(value = [CacheConfiguration::class])
class ServiceCacheTest {
    @MockBean
    private lateinit var persistenceService: PersistenceService

    @Suppress("unused")
    @MockBean
    private lateinit var rService: RService

    @Suppress("unused")
    @MockBean
    private lateinit var kafkaProperties: KafkaProperties

    @Suppress("unused")
    @MockBean
    private lateinit var producerFactory: ProducerFactory<String, Event>

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var service: UserService

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var redisTemplate: StringRedisTemplate

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {

        val mockProducer =
            mock<Producer<String, Event>>()

        whenever(producerFactory.createProducer()).thenReturn(mockProducer)
    }

    @Test
    fun `should call......

..........
```

Based on the answer provided below, I was able to get the expected behavior from the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a chain of mocks if you want that stubbed because you use a chain of `ProducerFactory` -> `Producer` -> `send`.  Both the `ProducerFactory` and `Producer` need to be mocked.  One problem in your setup is you are calling `producerFactory.createProducer()` on a mocked `producerFactory` which should be returning `null` by default.

This is how I would set it up

```
val producerFactory = mock<ProducerFactory<String, Event>>()
val mockProducer = mock<Producer<String, Event>()

whenever(mockProducerFactory.createProducer()).thenReturn(mockProducer)
```

You shouldn't be calling `producerFactory.createProducer()` nor `producer.send` directly in your mock setups.

You didn't specify the return type of `send` so I'm leaving that blank, but the above should be valid if doesn't return anything.  If you want to verify it was called then all you do is

```
verify(mockProducer).send(any())
```

Be forewarned that you didn't provide a lot of test code and you're still responsible for how the mock `ProducerFactory` gets injected into the production code you're testing.

Comment: I didn't quite understand why you paid attention to the inject ProducerFactory. I have given the code at the top, how it is implemented. And it works.

Comment: in addition, the plug for producer.send is only needed to simulate the response, the main check is the operation of the service and it is tested without problems. It's just that when I added a publication in Kafka to an existing service, my test class stopped running here.

Comment: I'm glad you got it going.  re: "I didn't quite understand why you paid attention to the inject ProducerFactory" probably being overcautious, but I just wanted to be clear for completeness (and for anyone else who may come across this).  You'd be surprised what leaving out "obvious" comments can cost sometimes.